# For LSTM variables I get error "tensorflow:Gradients do not exist for variables"

Tags: lstm, tensorflow2.0, lstm-stateful

Hi I have a **bidirectional LSTM layer:**

```
class BiDirLSTMInput(Layer):

  def __init__(self):
    self.bidir_lstm = Bidirectional(
                         LSTM(32, return_sequences=True,return_state=True)
                       )


  def call(self, input):
    o, h1,h2, c1,c2 = self.bidir_lstm(input)
    return [h1,h2]
```

As you can see, I am just consuming hidden state from LSTM (and not cell state)

Is that the reason, am I getting following warning:

WARNING:tensorflow:Gradients do not exist for variables for (backward layer):

1. lstm_cell_2/kernel:0',
2. lstm_cell_2/recurrent_kernel:0'
3. lstm_cell_2/bias:0'

Ignoring this doesn't sound logical. How do I deal with this error?

Answer (score 1):

Okay I am finally able to resolve this warning.

This was bit tricky to find it out what was wrong.

So basically what's happening was:

```
def call(self, input):
    o, h1,h2, c1,c2 = self.bidir_lstm(input)
    return (h1,h2)
```

As you can see, I was just **consuming hidden state and not cell state.**

That's the reason you see that gradient warning.

**Solution is:**

1. You just consume output state
2. If you want to consume hidden state then also consume cell state.

   **This you can do via multiple ways:**

   a) h_and_c = concat(h,c)

   b) h_and_c_avg = avg(h,c)

   c) h_and_c_sum = sum(h,c)

**Note** I have tested this with **Tensorflow Keras Bidirectional LSTM** (I haven't checked with just LSTM)

Answer (score 0):

I think, yes. Could you try consuming the `hidden states` as well and then observe whether you get the same warning or not?

Comment: Please check my answer below.